# VSCode Prettier not formatting CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, configuration, format, prettier

I am using the Prettier 5.1.3 extension in VSCode for Windows. It works very good with html but it doesn't work with css pages. I even reinstalled the whole VSCode, delete all settings files, reinstalled Prettier, enable "format on save" and set Prettier as default formatter but doesn't work. I noticed for html files if I run the Command Palette and look for "format" or if I click anywhere in the html file, I can see the options "Format Document" and "Format Document with", but in the css pages I can only see "Format Document" and it does nothing.

I would like to keep my VSCode as simpler as possible, without more extensions, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to set up Prettier to format CSS, since I have seen videos and examples where it works.

Thank you in advance for your help! =)

Comment: To format CSS code in Visual Studio Code I had to re-install Prettier. 
I uninstalled, restarted VSC, installed Prettier and now it works

Comment: This bug occurs if you install in "restrict" mode

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try installing vscode-css-formatter extension. It just adds the functionality to format .